# "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: message is too long"

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, reddit, praw, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm trying to retrieve messages from Reddit subreddits using [PRAW](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw). It is working properly for most of the cases but I'm getting the following error that the message is too long.I'm using [pytelegrambotApi](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI)

Snippet:

```
import praw
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)  

reddit = praw.Reddit(
    client_id=client, #these details are given accordingly and are correct. No errors here.
    client_secret=secret,
    user_agent="user_agent",
)

def get_posts(sub):
   for submission in reddit.subreddit(sub).hot(limit=10):
    print(submission)
    if submission.author.is_mod:
      continue
    elif submission.selftext=="":
      return submission.title,submission.url
    else:
      print("It's working")
      print(submission.url)
      return submission.title,submission.selftext 

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_message(message):
    subreddit = message.text
    title,post = get_posts(subreddit)
    m = title + "\n" + post
    bot.reply_to(message,m)

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Error:
[image: Error]
Is there any workaround that I can do possibly do here to access the full message?

Comment: How long is your longest message? You could try compressing it, sending it in two parts, storing it and providing a link for user access, etc.... There's loads of "workarounds" but I'd try to figure out what my limits are, and what my average/maximum lengths will be to decide what solution to implement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One Telegram message must contain no more than `4096` characters. The message is then split into another message (that is, the remainder).
Add this code to your `message_handler`:

```
m = title + "\n" + post
if len(m) > 4095:
    for x in range(0, len(m), 4095):
        bot.reply_to(message, text=m[x:x+4095])
else:
    bot.reply_to(message, text=m)
```

Comment: understood, thanks. One question though, I was wondering from where did you get the details of 4096 characters.

Comment: https://limits.tginfo.me/en